# Curl command on windows not passing user:pass correctly

Tags: windows, curl, command-prompt

I'm using CURL to execute some API calls against a bitbucket server.  The command is like this:

```
curl https://bitbucket.myserver.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/PRJ/repos/repo-slug/tags \
     -u 'user:pass' \
     -X POST \
     -H 'Content-type: application/json' \
     -d '{"name" : "test-tag", "message": "Test tag from curl", "startPoint": "master" }'
```

This is expected to create a tag on the master branch in the repo.  This however fails complaining of incorrect username/password.

I then copy/paste the command into git-bash prompt - and it works as expected, completing successfully. I tried this with multiple user accounts.  I also tried specifying only the username and then entering the password on command line - with the same results.

How can I get curl on windows to pass correct username/password to the server?

Comment: Are you using powershell? Are you using CMD.exe? How are you running this command?

Comment: This is using CMD.exe directly running at command prompt

Comment: There are different quoting rules for CMD. https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html

Comment: But what do I quote or escape? There are no special characters.

Comment: I see a lot of `'` and `"` characters. The single quotes are for escaping in shells but CMD does not recognize them. The rules for quoting `"` are different in CMD and other shells.

Comment: I see... unfortunately, it's not the issue here.  I tried with simply `-u user` without any quotes and entering the password at the prompt - to no avail.

Comment: The quoting IS wrong, so if you have not fixed all the quotes then it won’t work. Or you can just use Git Bash if you don’t want to learn the quoting rules for CMD, which is understandable.